# Hide td in html mail

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook

I want to send an email that will be opened in Outlook.
In this email I want to hide some empty `td`

This is my code :

```
<td width=""10%"" style="overflow: hidden;display:none;mso-hide:all;font-size: 0;max-height: 0; line-height: 0;"></td>
```

What I'm getting is this:

[image]

This `td` is like it has a 1px heigth, but not hidden.

Edit : add full table

```
<table border=1 align=""right""  style=""width: 49.5%;font-family:calibri;font-size:10pt;border-collapse:separate;" +
  @"border: 1px solid black;"">"

   @"<tr><th style=""font-family:calibri;font-size:10pt;background-color:#DDD9C4;"">Localisation</th>" +
                                   @"<th style=""font-family:calibri;font-size:10pt; background-color:#DDD9C4;"">Site</th>" +
                                   @"<th style=""font-family:calibri;font-size:10pt; background-color:#DDD9C4;width : 10%;"">Etat</th>" +
                                   @"<th style=""font-family:calibri;font-size:10pt;background-color:#DDD9C4;"">Commentaire</th> </tr>";

 bodytable = bodytable + "<tr>" +
                                  @"<td  style=""background-color:" + GetLocalisationColor(itemtheme.NomTheme) + @"""  rowspan=" + (itemlocation.Site.Count + 1) + ">" + itemlocation.NomLocalisation + "</td>" +

                                     @"<td  style=""overflow: hidden;display:none;mso-hide:all;font-size: 0;max-height: 0; line-height: 0;""></td>" +
                                               @" <td width=""10%"" style=""overflow: hidden;display:none;mso-hide:all;font-size: 0;max-height: 0; line-height: 0;""></td>" +
                                               @"<td  style=""overflow: hidden;display:none;mso-hide:all;font-size: 0;max-height: 0; line-height: 0;""></td>" +

                             " </tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

please try with this. you should change this as you need to use in email template

```
<table border=1 align="right" style="width:49.5%;font-family:calibri;font-size:10pt;border-collapse:separate;border: 1px solid black;">
   <tr>
      <th style="font-family:calibri;font-size:10pt;background-color:#DDD9C4;">Localisation</th>
      <th style="font-family:calibri;font-size:10pt; background-color:#ddd9c4;">Site</th>
      <th style="font-family:calibri;font-size:10pt; background-color:#ddd9c4;width:10%;">Etat</th>
      <th style="font-family:calibri;font-size:10pt;background-color:#ddd9c4;">Commentaire</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>       
      <td style="background-color:red"  rowspan="1"> itemlocation.nomlocalisation </td>
      <td style="overflow:hidden;display:none;mso-hide:all;font-size: 0;max-height:0; line-height:0;"></td>
      <td width="10%" style="overflow:hidden;display:none;mso-hide:all;font-size: 0;max-height:0; line-height:0;"></td>
      <td style="overflow:hidden;display:none;mso-hide:all;font-size: 0;max-height:0; line-height:0;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you please tell me what changes you made? i cannot see  any changes   (for the  `""` part  it's just  because it's is  in c# code  so you have  to overide the "  by two quotes

Comment: in your code there was some mistake like this. max-height 0; line-height 0;

Comment: Ok  think you but still  not working  .. the  td is not hiden  it's just  with a 1 px hight  (or less)

Comment: I try this for html page it works. may be you are missing something for email template

Comment: the problem is not in html   it's in Outlook  client , (it's working fine in html just with  `diplay:none`  ..but with outlook client  it's not  hiden